# jquery: How can I set in each input his maxlength value with data-val-length-max value?

Tags: jquery

I have a form which I want o set data-val-length-max attribute to MAXLENGTH attribute in jquery.

I have next input:

```
 <input type="text" id="name" data-val-length-max="20">
 <input type="text" id="lastname" data-val-length-max="10">
```

when page is loading I need to do that operation. I am executing next jquery:

```
$("input").attr("maxlength", $("input").attr("data-val-length-max"));
```

and maxlength is set as the value of first input .... in this case (name maxlength).

How can I do each input set maxlength with his own data-val-length-max value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's `attr()` only gets the attribute for the first element in the collection, from the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

> Get the value of an attribute **for the first element** in the set of matched elements

If you want to change the attribute of all the elements in the collection, you'd have to iterate, and a good way to do that would be to use a callback in `attr()`

```
$("input").attr("maxlength", function() {
    return  $(this).attr("data-val-length-max");
});
```

Comment: Why is this getting downvoted? Whoever did this, please explain.

Comment: @DmitriyDemir - someone obviously didn't get it, and decided to downvote? I've added some documentation from jQuery, to actually show that it's correct

Comment: Yeah, don't see any other reason... By the way, I've read somewhere that using `data` is heavier on performance than using `attr`, so maybe `$(this).attr("data-val-length-max")` would be slightly better? It also might help if this attribute is changed after the page is loaded, because data's value isn't getting updated when you change it with JS, if I remember right...

Comment: I believe you're right, as `data()` has to check jQuery's internal data-map before getting the data-attribute from the element, but I just tend to always use the `data()` method when accessing data-attributes etc. but I'll change it as what the OP has works just as well.

Comment: First code you set Dmitry was correct for me... this one it is working too sure but I keep  `$(this).data("val-length-max");`